# Vba adding data to table overwrites other data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, overwrite

I made a database for work, and made a form to add stuff to it, so the workers don't mess with the tables. It will always add the data, but sometimes instead of adding it to the bottom, it will overwrite another row of data. Sometimes not even an entire row, just a couple of the columns.
I've tried to do the code in two different ways.

```
    CurrentDb.Execute " INSERT INTO [Service Calls] " _
    & "([Project Name], [Phone Number], [email], [Source], [Service Address], [Zip Code], [Date of Service], [Type of Call], [Technician], [Ticket Number], [Invoice Number], [Total Billed], [Description of Work]) VALUES " _
    & "('" & Me.proj & "', '" & Me.phone & "', '" & Me.email & "', '" & Me.source & "', '" & Me.address & "', '" & Me.zip & "', '" & Me.doS & "', '" & Me.toC & "', '" & Me.tech & "', '" & Me.ticketNum & "', '" & Me.invoiceNum & "', '" & Me.billed & "', '" & Me.work & "');"
    CurrentDb.Close
```

and

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Service Calls")
With rst
 .AddNew
 .Fields("Project Name") = Me.proj
 .Fields("Service Address") = Me.address
 .Fields("Date of Service") = Me.doS
 .Fields("Technician") = Me.tech
 .Fields("Total Billed") = Me.billed
 .Fields("Zip Code") = Me.zip
 .Fields("Description of Work") = Me.work
 .Fields("Type of Call") = Me.toC
 .Fields("Invoice Number") = Me.invoiceNum
 .Fields("Ticket Number") = Me.ticketNum
 .Update
 End With
  rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
```

I am that one contains more data than the other. I used the top code when I updated the form.

Solved: Some fields in the form were bound. So, those items would occasionally overwrite. Once I unbound those fields, it would stop overwriting.

Comment: Neither the .AddNew or the 'Insert into' will overlay existing data in tables. Are the controls on your form BOUND or UNBOUND? If BOUND, I'm fairly certain the issue is your form displays a row of data and someone types into that row which changes the data. Is there other code elsewhere that could do it?

Comment: Some are BOUND, some are UNBOUND. I will UNBOUND all of them, and see if that fixes it. There is other code, but it only pulls up a query, so I don't think that does anything.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn add an answer to UNBOUND things in the form so I can say you gave me the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn: But the question will forever show up as unresolved. An answer would be better. (@Chris, you can write an answer too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since neither the .AddNew VBA or the 'Insert into' SQL will overlay existing data in tables, the cause is something else. If the controls on the form are BOUND, then simply typing into them will overlay the underlying record in the table. In your case, since you had a combination of bound and unbound controls, the bound controls caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What does 'sometimes' mean?  Computers don't sometimes do things and sometimes do other things.  Computers are deterministic, so some process works or it doesn't work.  It looks like it's setup as unbound now.  Can you make this process unbound or bound, and not mix the two?  That should fix the problem.